# JPA - equivalence of findByProperty() of EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

DAO provides `findByProperty(String propertyName, Object value)` to find objects using a specific attribute. But EntityManager in JPA only provides `find()` based on primary key search, see [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

To avoid writing SQL, is there equivalence of generic `findByProperty()` method for EntityManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Criteria` API in Hibernate . Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm)

Comment: Shud upvote or accept the answer if are satisfied :P

Comment: Which of course is NOT JPA ... and the question asked for JPA. Oh well

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

1. Use Critieria API suggested by @Viswanath L
2. Write your own `findByProperty()` which is identical to DAO's `findByProperty()` as below:

   ```
   public List<User> findByProperty(String propertyName, final Object value)
       try {
       final String queryString = "select model from **User** model where model."
                   + propertyName + "= :propertyValue";
           Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
           query.setParameter("propertyValue", value);
           return query.getResultList();
       } catch (RuntimeException re) {
           logger.error("find by property name failed", re);
           throw re;
       }
   }
   ```

Personally I prefer the second one as it's concise, and **the only modification is the table name.**  Moreover, this approach is flexible based on which you can write many versions of findByProperty().

Comment: Have an upvote for your second option. The first of course is not JPA, since he referred to Hibernate Criteria not JPA Criteria